# .htaccess - "friendly url" (slugs)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to create slugs to a localhost subdirectory.

I have this .htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteBase ^subdirectory/

RewriteRule ^subdirectory/search/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ subdirectory/search.php?q=$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/page/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ subdirectory/page.php?page_name=$1&page_id=$2 [L,R=301]
```

In search.php and page.php I have these codes:

search.php

```
<?php $q = $_GET[ 'q' ]; ?>
```

page.php

```
<?php
    $page_name = $_GET[ 'page_name' ];
    $page_id   = $_GET[ 'page_id' ];
?>
```

but for some reason, it gives only 404 error everytime, and if it doesn't, it works - but in the parent directory ("localhost", "www")

I've googled a lot but haven't found any solution yet.

`mod_rewrite` is enabled, so does `AllowOverride All`

using wamp server (v. 2.5) , apache 2.4.9

thank you all.

Comment: Do you have enabled `mod_rewrite` and setted `AllowOverride All` directive in your configuration file?

Comment: @Muriano update - I have checked, both of them enabled

Comment: you're repeating ^subdirectory string both RewriteBase and RewirteRule configuration, Could you try to change this?

Comment: @Muriano you mean to remove one of them?

Comment: yes. Try it removing RewriteBase directive, e.g.

Comment: @Muriano Even after removing RewriteBase it still gives 500 error

Comment: PHP and Apache error logs are registering some kind of error message?

Comment: @Muriano yes: `[Mon May 23 15:03:12.994483 2016] [core:alert] [pid 6072:tid 1040] [client ::1:52531] C:/wamp/www/subdirectory/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters` - apache error only

Comment: @Muriano apparently, the 500 error was because of the space between L to R=301 but now it shows 404 when I type "search/something" or page/something/1

Comment: @natanel97 No possibility of trying now but could you test if /search/xxxx/ gives 404 as well? Because your rule specifies that the address must end with a slash since you have /$ in the end. Try removing the last / so the $ comes after ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your .htaccess rules have several issues.

First of all, RewriteBase is supposed to set the root path so that you don't have to respecify it in every rule. In other words `RewriteBase /subdirectory/` means you don't have to include `subdirectory` in the actual RewriteRule statements.

Second your rules ends with `/$` meaning that it expects a trailing slash on the url. You can make it optional, skip it or have a separate rule that rewrites all urls without trailing slash.

Without changing that regex you can use /search/foobar/ and /page/foo/bar/ to make it work if you make the RewriteBase and relative url modificationin the .htaccess file accordingly:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteBase /subdirectory/

RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ search.php?q=$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ page.php?page_name=$1&page_id=$2 [L,R=301]
```

*PS. You probably want to remove the 301 as well since that actually redirects the user to the .php file paths.*

Comment: It still gives 404 error :\ I tried what you said also about the trailing slash (removed the $ sign) but still not working...

Comment: I would start by looking at logging because I successfully tried it on a standard Linux/Apache server. Enable tracing via LogLevel as detailed here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

Comment: @natanel97 I made a small demo on my dev server, will not be available forever but I'll leave it up for a few days: http://dirtylogic.org/test/

Comment: I saw it, thanks! but I don't know how to use LogLevel (new to .htaccess and I didn't really get how to use it)

Comment: LogLevel makes it show up in the actual log file of the webserver, i.e. your /var/log/apache/error_log or similar file depending on your VirtualHost configuration.

Comment: Well, you did great job and solved my problem. it was because of the trailing slash. I forgot to add it at the end (e.g. dir/search/someval/). thank you very much! but please can you help me understand how to make it optional?

Comment: and you were also right about the R=301 too! thanks again

Comment: @natanel97 Excellent, glad I could help!